# Ethereum Signing using HSM

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache, signature

I tried signing a Message using the **SHA256withECDSA** algorithm . It gives a different signed(r,s) output everytime. When i try to recover the address using the ecrevover method .it gives me a different address everytime.

Does it mean Ethereum requires a constant r,s value for message everytime?

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum uses keccak256 instead of sha256 for signing, so signatures generated by `SHA256withECDSA` cannot be verified by the EVM.